# How to adjust width of errorbar created with stat_summary_bin?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a grouped barplot with the following code. I want to adjust the width of errorbar to half of the
current width. However, the `width = 0.5` has no effect on the results. How should I do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
# ggplot2_2.2.1

df <- iris
set.seed(1)
df$group <- sample(c('I', 'II'), nrow(df), replace = T)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
    stat_summary_bin(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
                     geom = 'bar', position = 'dodge') +
    stat_summary_bin(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
                     geom = 'errorbar', position = 'dodge', width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ?geom_errorbar, see bottom
# Because the bars and errorbars have different widths
# we need to specify how wide the objects we are dodging are

dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = 'bar', position = dodge) +
stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = 'errorbar', position = dodge, width = 0.5)
```

Comment: While this produced the image I wanted, this does not work for `stat_summary_bin`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, currently not, maybe someone else?