# Plot bin averaged values with error bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, tapply

I have a dataframe with three columns "DateTime", "T_ET", and "LAI". I want to plot T_ET (on y-axis) against LAI (on x-axis) along with 0.1-bin LAI averaged values of T_ET on the same plot something like below (Wei et al., 2017):[image]

In above figure, y-axis is T_ET or T/(E+T), x-axis is LAI, red open diamonds with error bars are 0.1-bin LAI averaged of black points and the standard deviation, solid line is
a regression of the individual data points (estimated from the bin averages), n is available data points. Dash lines are 95% confidence bounds.

How can I obtain the plot similar to above plot? Please find the sample data using the following link: [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16UBiPCiDQH4rGAYJsznGQTcXqCQcEpcV/view?usp=sharing)

or use following sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1478088000, 1478347200, 1478692800, 1478779200, 1478865600, 1478952000, 1479124800, 1479211200, 1479297600, 1479470400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
                     T_ET = c(0.996408350852751, 0.904748351479432, 0.28771236118773, 0.364402232484906, 0.452348409759872, 0.415408041501318, 0.629291202120187, 0.812083112145703, 0.992414777441755, 0.818032913071265), 
                     LAI = c(1.3434, 1.4669, 1.6316, 1.6727, 1.8476, 2.0225, 2.3723, 2.5472, 2.7221, 3.0719)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Help us help you. Please provide some sample data. The result of `dput(head(df, 10))` can be enough to figure out how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I attached a link to the sample data. Now, I have edited as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly while plotting via `stat_summary_bin()`.  By default, the geom associated with this would be the `pointrange` geom and uses `mean_se()`.  `bins=` controls the number of bins, but you can also supply `binwidth=`.  Note that with the pointrange geom, `fatten` controls the size of the central point:

```
ggplot(df, aes(LAI, T_ET)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  stat_summary_bin(bins=3, color='red', shape=5, fatten=5)
```

[image]

Your sample data is a little light, so here's another example via the `diamonds` dataset.  Here, I'm constructing the same look as the example plot you show by combining the errorbar and poing geom.  Please note that [apparently setting the width of the errorbar doesn't work correctly with `stat_summary_bin()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418746/how-to-adjust-width-of-errorbar-created-with-stat-summary-bin).

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point(size=0.3) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='errorbar', color='red', bins=12, width=0.001) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='point', size=3, shape=5, color='red', bins=12) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

#### EDIT: Showing Regression for Binned Data

As indicated in the comments, drawing a regression line *based on the binned data and not the original data* is possible, but not through the `stat_summary_bin()` function unless you are okay to use `loess`.  If you're looking for linear regression, you'll need to bin the data outside of `ggplot`, then plot the regression on the binned data.

The reason for this is probably by design.  It's inherently not a good idea to draw a regression line (a way of summarizing data) that is based on summarized data.  Regardless, here's one way to do this via the `diamonds` dataset.  We can use the `cut()` function to cut into separate bins, then summarize the data on those binned values.  Due to the way the `cut()` function labels the output, we have to create our own labels.  Since we're cutting into 12 equal pieces in this example, I'm creating 12 evenly-spaced positions on the x axis for our data values to sit into - this may be different in your case, just take care you label according to what the data represents and what makes the most statistical sense.

```
df <- diamonds

# setting interval labeling
bin_width <- diff(range(df$carat)/12)
bin_labels <- c((range(df$carat)[1] + (bin_width/2))+(0:11*bin_width))

# cutting the data
df$bins <- cut(df$carat, breaks=12, labels=bin_labels)
df$bins <- as.numeric(levels(df$bins)[df$bins])    # convert factor to numeric

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point(size=0.3) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='errorbar', color='red', bins=12, width=0.001) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='point', size=3, shape=5, color='red', bins=12) +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(x=bins), method='lm', color='blue') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Note that the regression line above is *weighting all binned values equally*.  This is generally not a good idea unless your data is spaced evenly among the dataset.  **I'd still recommend if you're going to draw a regression line, have it linked to the original data**, which is much more representative of the reality within your data.  That would look like this:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point(size=0.3) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='errorbar', color='red', bins=12, width=0.001) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom='point', size=3, shape=5, color='red', bins=12) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', color='green') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

When it comes down to it, drawing a regression line for *binned* data is *summarizing the summarized data* rather than summarizing your original data.  It's statistical heresay, so use at your own risk.  But if you simply must for whatever strange reason... I can't stop you.  ;)

Comment: Thanks! What about adding a best fit regression line to bin averaged T_ET values ?

Comment: You can use the smooth geom with `stat_summary_bin`... although honestly if you're fitting a regression line I'd do that based on the non-binned data by just adding the regression line via `geom_smooth()` to your dataset.

Comment: It depends on the problem. My problem is like there is lot of noise if you look non-binned data. Binning helps removing that noise to some extent. geom="smooth" with stat_summary_bin is just joining the binned data points. But I want a best fit non linear curve as shown in the figure attached to the question.

Comment: Well, `stat_summary_bin(geom="smooth"...)` works fine for binned data, but is limited to the "loess" method (seems that `method="lm"` is not accepted there).  In this case, you will probably have to bin the data yourself separately, then overlay that binned data on top of the plot.

Comment: I got what you are saying. It would be great if you can edit your answer to show this using the diamond dataset.

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate how it's possible... but still not an advised way to summarize data.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Your point makes sense to me. But under certain cases, summarizing the bin-averaged data also makes sense. For example, if you see the figure I attached with my question, black data points come from different classes of crops. T_ET (y-axis) of different crops responds differently to LAI (x-axis). Here, goal is to show how T_ET of all the crops in general relate to LAI. There may be lot of noise due to particular crop class. To avoid this, first we do binning of the data to get data like between 0-1 LAI this is T_ET, 1-2 LAI this is T_ET, and so on.

Comment: Now, once we have binned data, we can show how binned T_ET and LAI are related. In your answer you fitted a linear model. Does ggplot support nonlinear fit as asked in my question? like T_ET = aLAI^b.

Comment: Yes, you can use basically type of fitting available in `R`, or even create your own function to apply if you know how.  [See the documentation for `geom_smooth()` for more information.](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html).  You access the type of fit to use via the `method` argument.  Within each of those, it's usually possible to use `plotmath` expressions to define the specific formula relationship, and you can define that via `formula` argument in `geom_smooth()`.  Default is `y ~ x`, but you can use `plotmath` expressions for other relationships to model.

Comment: More details on [plotmath syntax can be found here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).